# Veeva iRep Salesforce - unknown presentations/files downloaded on ipad sync

Tags: ipad, irepository

Three days ago when I've tried to sync the ipad to my Veeva CRM account(to get last updates for a presentation that I am working on) I've noticed that it was trying to download around 1000 files(presentations, videos, images) that I don't know anything about. I don't know how this can happen if those presentations are not even shared to me.
One day before it was all alright - no unknown files downloading.
Any clues? Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

New files would start to download via the media library if

- new presentations had been created and shared, or existing presentations had since been shared with you, or
- if you are using Vault integration with CLM, any new content had been approved in Vault and synced to CRM

Do you have admin or content admin access in your Veeva org? You will be able to check any content changes by looking at Key Messages tab (if you don't see it then use the + in your tab bar to get to 'All Tabs'). Then use the views to look at all key messages, and add the Last Modified date field in to the result set and then sort by Last Modified Date. This will give you an indication if there is new content in there.

The device would only sync content where the Last Mod date on Key Message has changed since last time you synced, there is nothing else that would prompt a content update.

Hope this helps, Stephen